# Chrome on Mac OSX Rendering Font in Basic Latin Blocks

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

The problem is that Chrome on Mac OSX appears to be rendering type in basic latin blocks. I do have a conditional stylesheet for IE that uses font-face, however I am not using font-face for anything other than IE. I'm guessing this might be an internal system font issue (error isn't on my own system), but I'd like to make sure.

Here is my CSS for this text:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Bold;
    src: url('type/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-bold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('type/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('type/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('type/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('type/helveticaneue/helveticaneue-bold.svg#helveticaneue-bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#Text {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Bold', Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Here is the CSS in the conditional stylesheet for IE:

```
#Text {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 670px;
    margin: 0 0 54px 0;
    color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

The text appears like this:

[image: Chrome rendering type in blocks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

April 2012 :

> Hopefully, the Google Chrome Development team is working on a solution for this, but  unfortunately, from what I can tell in researching the issue, this problem has been in place  for over a year and while it doesn’t affect Firefox, Safari or Opera, it doesn’t seem like there is any fix in the works by the Chrome team.

source :
http://www.jonathanjeter.com/web-development/browsers/google-chrome-mac-system-font-manager-problem/